# How to receive a message in the parent window from a button created by CreateWindow()?

Tags: c, winapi, button

I've created a button with the following code:

```
  HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",  // Predefined class;
        "Options",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        250,         // x position 
        0,         // y position 
        50,        // Button width
        30,        // Button height
        hwnd,     // Parent window
        NULL,       // No menu.
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);
```

I'm aware that messages from buttons can be received in the window procedure of the parent window by doing a `switch` with `WM_COMMAND` and the name of the control as the case, for example, `IDC_BUTTON`. However, that's only when I create buttons on dialog boxes graphically using Visual Studio's editor. When I create a button using `CreateWindow`, as above, there isn't a 'name' for the control to put into a case statement.

What message is sent to the parent window when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the button's identifier value (as in the `IDC_BUTTON1` control resource ID, for example, in a dialog box) as the `hMenu` argument in the call to `CreateWindow`.

Here's a suitably modified version of your code:

```c
  HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",  // Predefined class;
        "Options",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        250,       // x position 
        0,         // y position 
        50,        // Button width
        30,        // Button height
        hwnd,      // Parent window
        (HMENU)(IDC_BUTTON1), // With WS_CHILD, this is an ID, not a menu
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);
```

From the description of the `hMenu` parameter [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) (bold emphasis mine):

> A handle to a menu, or specifies a child-window identifier depending
> on the window style. For an overlapped or pop-up window, *hMenu*
> identifies the menu to be used with the window; it can be **`NULL`** if the
> class menu is to be used. ***For a child window, *hMenu* specifies the
> child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box control
> to notify its parent about events.*** The application determines the
> child-window identifier; it must be unique for all child windows with
> the same parent window.

Then, when the parent receives the `WM_COMMAND` message, that identifier value will be *part* (the low word) of the `wParam` argument (the high word will be the `BN_CLICKED` notification code). ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command))

So, assuming you have the `IDC_BUTTON1` token defined somewhere, and pass that as the `hMenu` argument as described above, then your parent window can have something along the following lines as part of the message-handler's `switch` statement:

```c
//...
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1 && HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Clicked My Button!", "Testing...", MB_OK);
            // <Place your actual code here ...>
            return 0; // If handled, we should return zero.
        }
        break;
//...
```